# Push notifications from server to user with PHP/JavaScript

Tags: php, jquery, http, cordova

**Short:** Is there a way to push data from the server to a logged in user session without that user needing to make an HTTP request?

**Long(er):** I'm building an HTML5 application, on an Apache/PHP/MySQL server, that could be served to users on mobile devices (or perhaps via a PhoneGap application).

I would like to let the user know when there is new information available from the application, without racking up excessive data charges by forcing that user to execute a call to the server, or requiring AJAX calls (yes I know it could check for a single byte cookie, but I'd rather make it zero).

A good example of this would be sending chat messages between two users on submit from one user to the other.

Comment: I'm doing my research into WebSocket's thanks to the feedback I've recieved. I found an awesome tutorial over at: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/start-using-html5-websockets-today

Comment: Why was this closed? It's a real question ...

Comment: It is a real question, but one that is broad and not clear. An 'obvious' answer would be, "ofcourse", as sure, there are ways to push data from a server without using HTTP, for instance using ANY other protocol. The problem seems to be 'excessive data charges', but how would another protocol fix that? It looks like 'sockets' is the answer, but that's not a real obvious thing to suggest based on the contents of the question in my opinion.. Maybe if the question is clarified a bit?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In modern browsers, [Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/WebSockets) or in older browsers, "[long polling](http://dsheiko.com/weblog/websockets-vs-sse-vs-long-polling)".  There are also libraries that can abstract some of this (like [comet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_%28programming%29)).

A very common library in use now is [`socket.io`](http://socket.io/) which automatically connects with the best technology available, using webSockets if available and falling back to other technologies like long polling if not available.

Some other references:

[How do I implement basic "Long Polling"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code)

[COMET (server push to client) on iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337985/comet-server-push-to-client-on-iphone)

[More on Long Polling](http://cometdaily.com/2007/11/16/more-on-long-polling/)

[Is there a difference between long-polling and using Comet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570824/is-there-a-difference-between-long-polling-and-using-comet)

[Pushing the web with websockets](http://www.slideshare.net/rmoriz/pushing-the-web-websockets)

[Oh HTML5, Push Data to my Mobile](http://www.webofthings.org/2011/10/24/websockets-push-to-mobile/)

Comment: Superbly helpful. I'll start doing my homework on Websockets ASAP.

Comment: Added socket.io reference which is now very useful.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend [Socket.io](http://socket.io)

It leverages

> WebSocket, FlashSocket, HTML file(for IE), XHR long-polling, JSONP-polling

It is with [Node.js](http://nodejs.org) which means it is on non-blocking nature.

In realtime feature, concurrency is a big issue

so the non-blocking nature of Node.js and Socket.io would help you

Comment: I'm wary of Node.js, but this is very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[ScaleDrone](https://www.scaledrone.com) lets you push from PHP to JavaScript using a [PHP API client](http://docs.scaledrone.com/php).