# Handle HTTP XML stream in javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, http, stream

I am writing a web application for my company. The company has a server that I have to use and I can not change anything on the server side.

When I send an HTTP GET request I get a stream of XML as response, i.e. the HTTP connection remains opened until it is closed manually. When I test the request in my browser I immediately get the response which is updated automatically every time the data changes (and because it is a stream, the loading animation of the browser keeps running).

How can I handle the response in javascript? Is there any way I can get notified when the data changes? I have done research for available frameworks to handle this but without any luck.

Comment: You will need to set up an interval and Ajax the data and compare to previously gotten data

Comment: Is there no way to get notified when the data has updated rather than polling the data everytime? It is a stream, not a regular response.

Comment: You may want to use notifications, loot at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106516/push-notifications-from-server-to-user-with-php-javascript) that may help you out dude !

Answer (score 0):

There is a SAX parser written in JavaScript which would be useful in an architecture such as:

- Company Server
- WebSocket stream
- Sax.js

**References**

- [Sax-js](https://github.com/isaacs/sax-js)
- [npm:websocket-stream](https://www.npmjs.org/package/websocket-stream)
- [NodeJS Stream Playground](http://ejohn.org/blog/node-js-stream-playground/)