# Which of today's JS website framework support messages pushed from the server to the client?

Tags: javascript, messaging

I would like to build a website using a browser-side JS framework. Most likely a SPA based on MVC. One important feature that I need from such a framework is the ability for my web server to push a notification to the browser. For example when a long-running async process on the serverhas completed successfully and I'd like to notify a particular client.

I am having a hard time understanding which of today's modern JS frameworks (ex: Knockout, Ext etc.) have this built-in. I'm not even sure how this feature is called. Might anyone know?

Comment: maybe you can use websockets? it's HTML5

Comment: Thanks. I'm definitely interested in WebSockets for this, but I'm looking for a framework that will wrap around these and fit them into its MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a good previously asked `StackOverflow` discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106516/push-notifications-from-server-to-user-with-php-javascript)

And

[Push notifications using `Node.Js`](https://blog.engineyard.com/2013/developing-ios-push-notifications-nodejs)

Comment: Not quite relevant to the question, but useful anyway. Thanks.