# Alert all viewers in my page?

Tags: javascript, popup, alert

My question is a little bit difficult, let me explain:

I have a webpage for 10-15 workers and I want to click a button on my PC (a simple html button or something like that), and then when you press it, it appears an alert or pop-up in the screen of all the people that is on the webpage.

It's that possible?? Thanks :)

Comment: can you create an JSON object or array on server side whenever your page got connected ??

Comment: A helpful stack answer, maybe... [Push notifications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9106516/push-notifications-from-server-to-user-with-php-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is kind of easy to do with websockets ([socket.io](http://socket.io/)).

You'd do something like this on the server side

```
socket.broadcast.emit('alert', 
{
    message: 'Alarm!'
});
```

And something like this on the client side:

```
socket.on('alert', function (data) 
{
    alert(data.message);
});
```

Using sockets is probably the easiest way to achieve this, but if you have not used them before it is going to take some time.